# Yii2 excel import 'PHPExcel_IOFactory' not found

Tags: php, excel, import, yii2

I want to read the excel record in Yii2, for that i search a extension and finally i got the following extension

Extension :
http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii2-phpexcel/#add-comment

After successful installation via composer, i put the code

```
namespace app\controllers;
use app\models\TempCdr;
use app\models\User;
use yii\web\UploadedFile;
use yii;



class BatchController extends \yii\web\Controller
{

    public  $user_model;
    public  $allowed_file_extension = array('xls','xlsx');

    public function init() {
        $fileName = 'assets/CdrTmp/cpyCdr.xls';
        $data = \moonland\phpexcel\Excel::import($fileName);
    }


 }
```

in my index controller, but it was throw the error Class 'PHPExcel_IOFactory' not found.

**My folder structure after install the extension**

```
moonlandsoft
 Excel.php
 composer.json

phpoffice
 phpexcel
   Documentation
   Examples
   src
```

**Json update**

```
 "phpoffice/phpexcel": "^1.8",
 "moonlandsoft/yii2-phpexcel": "*"
```

May i know what is the problem on that, thanks in advance for your idea and suggestion .

Comment: Post the full controller code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `PHPExcel_IOFactory` class file is in the `phpoffice/phpexcel` package, which is a dependency of the `yii2-phpexcel` extension. Please make sure that you have *successfully installed* the extension. You could take a look at the `vendor` directory, and check if there is a following structure:

```
...
moonlandsoft/
...
phpoffice/
    phpexcel/
        Classes/
            PHPExcel/
                IOFactory.php
...
```

If not, you could reinstall the `yii2-phpexcel` extension.

In order to answer your question, I installed the extension on my application, and put the following snippet in an action:

```
$fileName = '/tmp/a.xls';
$data = \moonland\phpexcel\Excel::import($fileName);
print_r($data);
```

The `$data` was printed correctly. Then, I renamed the `phpexcel` directory in `vendor/phpoffice` to `phpexcel2`. This time, I reproduced your error message:

[image: Class 'PHPExcel_IOFactory' not found]

Comment: I have installed both the extension via the composer 1)require --prefer-dist moonlandsoft/yii2-phpexcel "*" 2)composer require phpoffice/phpexcel, but the folder structure is not like you mention, see the question update for your better understanding